# Typescript React: How to add a .pdf file to src folder?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf, module

I am trying to add my resume .pdf file to my portfolio site, the goal is for the file to download once a button is clicked. I added my .pdf file and a types.s.ts folder to my src folder.

I imported my pdf file into my Resume.tsx component:

`import resumePDF from "../src/Resume.pdf";`

button for download:

```
<a href={resumePDF}>
    <button id="resume-button">Download Resume</button>
</a>
```

I am encountering the following error with the code above:

```
ERROR in src/Resume.tsx:2:23
TS2307: Cannot find module '../src/Resume.pdf' or its corresponding type declarations.
    1 | import React from "react";
  > 2 | import resumePDF from "../src/Resume.pdf";
      |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 |
    4 | function Resume() {
    5 |   return (
```

When I go to the types.s.ts file, I am seeing the following error:

```
ERROR in src/types.s.ts:1:16
TS2664: Invalid module name in augmentation, module '*.pdf' cannot be found.
  > 1 | declare module "*.pdf";
      |                ^^^^^^^
    2 |
    3 | export default module;
    4 |
```

From what I have been reading, I am supposed to add export to the bottom of the types.s.ts file, but I am not sure what else to add here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- you need to install `types/node` using this command:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/node
```

2- put your pdf in the public folder that React creates by default :

[image: put your pdf in the public folder that React creates by default]

3- create `types.s.ts` file in the `src` folder:

```
function getPDFURL(pdfFile: string): string {
    return pdfFile;
  }
export default getPDFURL;
```

4- in the component that you want to add the download button:

```
//import first:
import  pdf  from "./types.s";

// then create resumePDF using pdf function:
const resumePDF = pdf("Resume.pdf");

//finally use resumePDF in your jsx:
<a href={resumePDF}>
      <button id="resume-button">Download Resume</button>
</a>
```

**Note:** If you want the user to download the pdf instead of opening it you can add the `download` attribute to the `a` tag like this:

```
<a href={resumePDF} download>
  <button id="resume-button">Download Resume</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Anytime, I hope this helps.